Azure style notification panel in ASP.Net
Using ASP.NET, is there anyway to design a notification panel similar to the Azure notifications, that pops up on the right side of the browser window on click?
Please see the attached screenshot. I searched online and couldn't find any useful results.
Thank you


The Azure portal is a web application, so it is indeed possible to replicate its interface in a web application.  What have you tried and what didn't work as expected?

I am looking for an efficient way to replicate this along with the functionality. Never worked with notifications before, so any pointers are helpful.

Are you asking how to push data from the server to the browser?  Something else?  Narrow the problem to something more specific.  If you're looking for ready-made solutions or recommendations for 3rd party tools, this community doesn't offer that.

Such notifications are often called toast messages.
You can certainly adopt such a UI in your applications, but the real question, the real issue is how and when you want to display such notifications?
In other words, the issue then becomes do you just need in some cases to display use a UI message based on some user interaction, say like this:

Or, are you looking to have such messages display while the user is not doing anything at all?
In other words, do you require what are called push notifications?
By push, this means the message is triggered by the server side, and not the client side.
In above, since I clicked on a button, then I am free to display a message, even a toast one.
However, if you need push notifications (when the user does not interact with the page)?
Well, then you need a technology stack in which the server can now push out notifications to the browser.
You could then say just add some JavaScript with a timer, and say call a web method every few seconds.
Or, you can adopt a real time live connection to the server based on a web socket, and that will allow push notifications to occur from the server. This technology stack is how chat pages work in that as each user types, the web pages is updated in real time.
Since it can take significant work to build and setup a web socket on your own, then in most cases it is better to adopt an existing framework based on web sockets.
Hence, if you need server-side push notifications, then best to adopt say SignalR.
So, you need to adopt a web socket that allows pushing of information from the server.
Hence, something like SignalR would be the best choice here. In addition to adopting some push stack, you then need some type of toast library, of which there are 100's to choose from.
You can start with SignalR here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-signalr
